# List Comprehension returns none but I don't have anything that can result in none

Tags: macos, python-2.7

```
list_of_strings = ["a", "2", "7", "zebra"]

def safe_int(list):
    try:
        list[i] = int(list[i])
    except ValueError:
        list[i] = 0

new_list = [safe_int(list_of_strings) for i in range(len(list_of_strings))]

print new_list
```

## expected result : [0, 2, 7, 0]

## outcome : [None, None, None, None]

Comment: Should i be defined and initialized before using
add `i=0` after the list definition

Comment: You are building a list (`new_list`) accumulating what is returned by `safe_int(...)` — now ask yourself "What is returning the function `safe_int()`?" If I ask myself, I'll answer "nothing!" or, in Python terms, it returns `None`.  Hence your result... — On the other hand, have you tried to print the content of `list_of_strings` AFTER the list comprehension?

Comment: Thank you so much gboffi, You helped me so much. But just out of curiosity,  would it be possible to assign the output of safe_int() directly to another new list

Comment: Hi Amine, I have just posted what I think is a good, detailed answer to your problem.

Comment: Thank you so much, your program worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Define your function so that it *returns* the result of the conversion or the number zero

```
def safe_int(l, i):
    try:
        return int(l[i])
    except ValueError:
        return 0
```

(note that I've passed explicitly `i` to the function because the value of `i` in the list comprehension is visible in the function due to a bad design decision in Python 2 that was corrected in Python 3) and then build the `new_list`

```
 new_list = [ safe_int(list_of_strings, i) for ...]
```

I have to say that your approach is not idiomatic, I'd prefer to write

```
def safe_int(a_string):
    try:
        return int(a_string)
    except ValueError:
        return 0

new_list = [safe_int(s) for s in list_of_strings]
```